# Can't log in to ubuntu 12.04 server

Tags: authentication, passwords, ubuntu-12.04

I have an ubuntu 12.04 server.  My password is long and before I can fully enter the password, the login timesout.  I can't get into the box to change this timeout time.  Is there anything else I can do?

Answer (score 0):

Write the password on a texteditor, copy it and when the server asks for it, paste it. That should speed things up and is what I would do. Don't forget to delete the password from the texteditor after that. And for some reason I feel like this is a [Server fault](https://serverfault.com/) question.

Comment: I'm directly on the computer.  I can't ssh into it.

Comment: I thought you were doing it using something like a terminal or putty. That is a big problem. Try asking it on [Server fault](http://serverfault.com/). I'm not sure how to go about it.